# Running Angular Universal app fails - won't compile app.module.ts from separate project or recognize service

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to turn my Angular app to Angular Universal SSR app.
The project includes a separate application module in projects folder at the root of the app (ng generate application), which is exported at the main app.module.ts and included in app-routing-module.ts. The application executes fine with ng serve and adding universal support returned no errors.
However, when I run `npm run build:ssr -and npm run serve:ssr` in PowerShell, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(35,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Could not resolve projects/{project name}/src/app/app.module relative to [object Object].. 
src/app/components/home/home.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/xxx.service'.
src/app/app-routing.module.ts(3,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'projects/{project name}/src/app/app.module'.
src/app/components/xxx/xxx.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/xxx.service'.
src/app/components/yyy/yyy.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/xxx.service'.
src/app/components/qqq/qqq.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/xxx.service'.
src/app/app.module.ts(7,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'projects/{project name}/src/app/app.module'.
```

The problem is not only with the app in the projects folder but also the fact that it cannot find the only service in the 'normal' directory.
How could I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Please use unix like relative import paths instead of absolute import paths, e.g., in `src/app/components/home/home.component.ts(2,30)`, use something like `../path` to `home.component.ts`.